# Dynamically expanding array of structs C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

So for my school project, a large CSV file will be entered through `stdin` and we will have to sort it based on column and print it out as a sorted csv file.

The step I am on right now is figuring out how to keep `realloc`ing a `struct` of arrays so that it will grow if there is not big enough to hold the data coming in from `stdin`. We don't know the exact amount of rows that will be inputted in the CSV file. Right now we just used a static amount to test and see if the values are assigned to the `struct`s.

I am still a beginner at C so I do not clearly know how I would iterate through a pointer like I would iterate through an array. Since we are using a static amount of `struct`s in the array, we can just iterate using `array[i]` like in Java but how would you iterate through something like `*array`?

I do not know where to start for creating this dynamic array. I tried

```
struct array* testArray = (array*)malloc(sizeof(testArray));
```

but I have no idea how to iterate through it like I did with the static array by using `array[i]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, sorry for the wall of text...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you should be able to iterate it the same way

Comment: `struct array* testArray = (array*)malloc()` this seems doubly wrong, are you sure you're not doing *C++*. `struct array` and `array` are different things in C; and casting of return value of `malloc` shouldn't be done in C (while it is strictly necessary in C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct array* testArray = (array*)malloc(sizeof(testArray));
```

is a little wrong as you only allocate 1 element of testArray.

It is more like:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    ....
};

struct A* arr = malloc( N * sizeof(struct A) );
                       ^^^
                       N element of struct A

int j;
for (j=0; j<N; ++j)  // Iterate it like any other array
{
    arr[j].a = 5;
    arr[j].b = 42;
    ....
}
```

Use `realloc` when you need the array to grow.

When reading from a file/stdin it could look like (based on comment from David C. Rankin):

```
int n=0; // Count of the number of structs read from the file

struct A* arr = malloc( N * sizeof(struct A) );
while (read line from file)
{
    arr[n].a = val1; 
    arr[n].b = val2; 
    ++n;              // Increment count
    if (n == N)       // Check if current array is full, i.e. realloc needed
    { 
       // realloc array to 2 * N; N = N * 2 
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `for (j=0; j<N; ++j)`, why not just keep track of the number of array elements filled and `realloc` once `N` elements are reached? (pseudo code) `int n=0; while read line; arr[n].a = val; arr[n].b = val; if (++n = N) { realloc array to 2 * N; N = N * 2 }` and keep going until the file is read?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I focused on simple examples for allocating and iterating. When reading from a file/stdin, your code is a better example. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: `sizeof(testArray)` allocates space only for one pointer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - that was I wrote - "1 element of testArray" - since testArray is a pointer, it is 1 pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate through a malloced space the same way as with an array (using indicies), but it seems that your main issue lies in your use of malloc. Malloc's argument is the size in number of *bytes* that you want to allocate. So if you want to have an array of structs, you would first need to find out how many bytes one struct contains using `sizeof(struct array)`, and then determine how large of an array you want, let's say `N`. So that line of code should look more like `struct array* testArray = malloc(N * sizeof(struct array));`. The return value of malloc will be a void pointer containing the memory address of the first byte of allocated space. Upon assigning this value to testArray, it will be type-casted to the assigned variable type (`struct array *`). Now you can use pointer arithmetic to access a specific index `i` with `*(testArray + i)`, or simply testArray[i]. If you find that `N` was not a sufficient size, you can use realloc to increase the array size to `2N`, or whatever size deemed necessary.